# Kubernetes pod unreachable

Tags: kubernetes

I've got this bizarre issue where a pod in one of my environments isn't allowing requests through on the port specified

From another pod:

```
/app # wget 10.12.2.22:6000
Connecting to 10.12.2.22:6000 (10.12.2.22:6000)
wget: error getting response`
```

From the service:

```
/app # wget services:6000
Connecting to services:6000 (10.15.249.82:6000)
wget: error getting response: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

From inside itself:

```
/app # wget localhost:6000
converted 'http://localhost:6000' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'http://localhost:6000' (UTF-8)
--2018-10-03 01:26:39--  http://localhost:6000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:6000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-10-03 01:26:39 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Here's my YAML:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: services
  namespace: production
  labels:
    name: services
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: services
      version: production
  template:
    metadata:
      name: services
      labels:
        app: services
        version: production
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: services
        image: gcr.io/myproject/services:v1.6.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: "gc-serviceaccount"
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: "/app/secrets"
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 3000
          protocol: TCP
        - name: sockets
          containerPort: 6000
          protocol: TCP
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: "local"
        - name: PORTAL_HOST
          value: "portal.myproject.com"
        - name: PORTAL_HOSTNAME
          value: "http://portal"
        - name: DESIGNER_HOSTNAME
          value: "http://designer"
        - name: FILE_HOST
          value: "https://files.myproject.com"
        - name: STORAGE_BUCKET
          value: "production"
        - name: DATA_PATH
          value: ""
        - name: MONGO_DB_NAME
          value: "MyProject"
        - name: MONGO_REPLICA_SET
          value: "myproject"
        - name: PORT
          value: "3000"
        - name: REDIS_HOSTNAME
          value: "redis"
        - name: REDIS_PORT
          value: "6379"
        - name: SOCKETCLUSTER_WS_ENGINE
          value: "ws"
        - name: SOCKETCLUSTER_PORT
          value: "6000"
        - name: CLIENT_HOST
          value: "myproject.com"
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 3000
          periodSeconds: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 10

      volumes:
      - name: "gc-serviceaccount"
        secret:
          secretName: "gc-serviceaccount"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: services
  namespace: production
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  - name: sockets
    port: 6000
    targetPort: sockets
  selector:
    app: services
```

It's worth noting that I have no issues when trying to connect to the pod from another pod on port 3000.

So far I created a new environment and deployed to that but I'm receiving the same error.

Strangely enough, my other, older environments work fine, so I'm wondering if it's a Kubernetes issue?

Comment: Could you see if /healthz is returning 200/OK within one second? Otherwise it will not be added to service/ip-tables rules.

Comment: You are able to connect to ur Pod on port `3000` but not in `6000`. Am I right ?

Comment: Further investigation by using Morgan on Express.js I can see requests to 6000 are receiving a request successfully, but appears that responses are not being returned.

    GET / 200 0.564 ms - 9 
    GET / 200 0.719 ms - 9
    GET /healthz 200 0.397 ms - 2
    GET /healthz 200 0.597 ms - 2

Comment: So no probs with pod/kubernetes ?

Comment: There still could be - I can get a response successfully if I wget locally. Morgan only tells me that endpoints are being hit, it doesn't tell me that responses are correctly sent. So it feels as though the responses aren't finding away back to the requestor.

Comment: could you please share more information about the architecture so I can try to recreate this? get services, endpoints and pods results.